# NSDateFormatter completion

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSTextField with NSDateFormatter. The formatter accepts 'mm/dd/yy'.

Is it possible to complete the date automatically? So the user can type 'mm' and the formatter completes the current month and year.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use an `NSDatePicker`? (It does require 10.4 and later, but that's less of an issue these days)...

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know there such a thing on MacOS X. If you like post your solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason you don't want to use an [NSDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePicker_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? (It does require 10.4 and later, but that's less of an issue these days)...

Answer (score 0):

No.

You are going to need some logic that detects when "mm" is present in the text field and then get the current date from NSDate and then pass that into the date formatter to get the string and then display it in the text field.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stick with NSDatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

You could also investigate the various delegate methods available to NSTextField. If my memory serves me right, there is didBeginEditing (which is inherited from NSControlTextEditingDelegate, check that class reference). However, I'm not sure if that fires every time you input a new character...though it may. In which case it'd be a case of assigning a delegate that checks the NSText string and does a little comparison.

Comment: Good idea. There's indeed a method called `controlTextDidBeginEditing`.